# What is the best choice given a probability and a cost for each choice?

Tags: probability, optimization

I've been dealing with this problems for a few hours now and think I could use some outside help.

The scenario is the following: We are given different choices with each one having a probability of success and a cost associated with it, which one is the correct one, understanding as correct the one that makes the best use of our money?

```
| Option   | Cost(c) |  Probability(P)   |
+----------|---------|-------------------+
| Option a | 2       |    0.9            |
| Option b | 1       |    0.8            |
| ...      | ...     |    ...            |
| Option n | 3       |    0.92           |
```

My approach is that we can calculate the effectiveness of an option (`R`) with the following formula:

$$ R(P, c) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P (1-P)^{i} c(i+1)$$

I calculated `R` for a few pairs of `(P, c)` with the above expression and notice that the results obtained could be expressed in a much simpler way:

$$ R(P, c) = c (\frac{1}{P}) $$

My questions are: Is this the best approach to the problem or there are alternatives ways of calculating the best option? Can really the first expression be expressed as the second or am I missing something?

Edit: In case you want to compute `R` in your computer, if you have Python you can use:

```
def r(cost, performance):
    result = 0.0
    if performance > 0:
        for i in range(0, 1000):
            result += performance * ((1 - performance) ** i) * cost * (i+1)
        return result
    else:
        return -1
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would have thought you need an expression for the value of success, in the same units as the cost. Then you simply need to optimise the expected profit, Pv - c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It rather depends on the constraints of your problem.  Are you allowed multiple attempts? Are you allowed multiple successes?

If the value of a success (ignoring the cost of the attempts) is $s$ then the value of one attempt by a particular option $j$ is $sp_j-c_j$.  If you are allowed only one attempt then this is what you should be maximising. If you are allowed multiple attempts and multiple successes then this is also what you should be maximising.

But if you are allowed multiple attempts but only one success, then your approach produces a correct result.  You have a [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), and so you want to maximise  $s-\frac{c_j}{p_j}$, which for fixed $s$ is the same as minimising $\frac{c_j}{p_j}$ or maximising $\frac{p_j}{c_j}$.

It is certainly true that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (i+1) p (1-p)^{i} = \frac1p$ for $0 \lt p \le 1$.